# How to get row number without windows functions in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Assume there is the following table schema and data

```
create table tbl(
    id integer primary key,
    name text,
    pid integer
);

insert into tbl
values
    (1,'d',0),
    (2,'c',1),
    (3,'b',1),
    (4,'e',1),
    (5,'b',0),
    (6,'a',0);
```

It is a one-level depth hierarchy of parent and child items.

I need to aggregate children names into their parents like so

```
 id | name | children_names
----+------+------------
  6 | a    |
  1 | d    | c, e, b
  5 | b    |
```

`children names` need to be sorted within each row and the entire result need to be sorted by `name` column alphabetically, but all `b` names must always go last.

In PostgreSQL I would do it with `row_number() over()` window function like this

```
with
t as (select * from tbl order by name),
t2 as (select * from t where name<>'b' union all select * from t where name='b'),
t3 as (select *, row_number() over() from t2)
select a.id, a.name, string_agg(b.name, ', ' order by b.row_number)
from t3 a left join t3 b on a.id=b.pid and a.id<>b.id
where a.pid=0
group by a.id, a.name, a.row_number
order by a.row_number
```

but I need this in Android Room which lacks window functions yet.

So how to get the same result without window functions used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort `group_concat()` values, the original rows must come from an ordered subquery:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       group_concat(cname) AS children_names
FROM (SELECT p.id,
             p.name,
             c.name AS cname
      FROM      tbl AS p
      LEFT JOIN tbl AS c ON p.id = c.pid
      WHERE p.pid = 0
      ORDER BY c.name = 'b',
               c.name)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY name = 'b',
         name;
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for! Just the last `order by` should be changed to `ORDER BY name='b', name` and it works perfect. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite have no `STRING_AGG()` function.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name), '') children_names
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.id = t2.pid
WHERE t1.pid = 0
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=69b70ab7afb806d3b7096ac1db003fe2)

`GROUP_CONCAT()` have no `ORDER BY` clause. No way to affect on the concatenated values order.

PS. Of course you may try to emulate ordered concatenation using recursive CTE with concatenating values one-by-one in the order which you need, but this CTE will be too complex and, I think, this makes no sense.

PPS. If you need to get ROW_NUMBER() without window function by some field/expression **which is unique** you may use [this trick](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ce7e58a7fc977f1012e371bbd02c2371).

Comment: is there a way to make `b` values apear at the end of the list with this technique?

Comment: @yaugenka Yes. [One more trick](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6e132b3f247aa071f85636e664b610ed) - absolutely unsupportable.

Comment: wow that's becoms too complicated. There is a simpler solution from CL below.